# Why is my hover effect not following my elements when elements are moved via window resizing?

Tags: html, css

I have 7 images in a row with each surrounded by  tags. When I hover over one of the images, I have a pop up block right above the image and centered. However, this position only applies when I'm in full screen. When I resize the window, the hover pop up block does not maintain the same position as when the window is in full screen. How can I maintain that original position with the pop up block centered above the image when I move the images through window resizing?

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .imgs {
        display: block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 577px) {
    .imgs {
        display: block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .imgs {
        display: block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
    }
}

#userNames {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
}

#usersW {
    width: 14.2%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.showMore {
    display: block;
    width: max-content;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
}

.fonts {
    font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3vw;
}


/* Hover effect on user profiles */

a .content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 125px;
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 6px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform: translatex(-25%) translatey(-50px);
}

a .content:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
    bottom: -10px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    left: 140px;
}

a:hover .content {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translatex(-25%) translatey(0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="list-group-item clearfix mt-2 mr-2 mb-2 ml-0">
    <h1 class="ml-4 mt-1 mb-2 fonts">Users</h1>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div *ngFor="let user of users" id="usersW">

                        <a href="#">
                            <img [src]="user.profilePic" class="mx-auto my-1 p-1 imgs">
                            <p id="userNames">{{ user.name }}</p>
                            <div class="content">
                                <img [src]="user.imgPath[0]" class="mx-auto p-2 imgs">
                            </div>
                        </a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="mx-auto mt-4 showMore">Show More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .imgs {
        display: block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 577px) {
    .imgs {
        display: block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .imgs {
        display: block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
    }
}

#userNames {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
}

#usersW {
    width: 14.2%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.showMore {
    display: block;
    width: max-content;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
}

.fonts {
    font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3vw;
}


/* Hover effect on user profiles */

a .content {

position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
margin-left: -150px;
margin-top: -150px;
    background: red;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 6px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
transform: translatex(-25%);
    
}

a .content:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
    bottom: -10px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    left: 140px;
}

a:hover .content {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
transform: translatex(0%);
    
}
```

```html
<div class="list-group-item clearfix mt-2 mr-2 mb-2 ml-0">
    <h1 class="ml-4 mt-1 mb-2 fonts">Users</h1>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div *ngFor="let user of users" id="usersW">

                        <a href="#">
                            <img [src]="user.profilePic" class="mx-auto my-1 p-1 imgs">
                            <p id="userNames">{{ user.name }}</p>
                            <div class="content">
                                <img [src]="user.imgPath[0]" class="mx-auto p-2 imgs">
                            </div>
                        </a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="mx-auto mt-4 showMore">Show More</a>
</div>
```